# Adding thickness to a 2D sprite when turning

Tags: java, libgdx, glsl

In my game, my entities turn like a piece of paper, as shown here at half-speed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmDNQ.jpg 
I want to give the entities a bit of thickness when they turn, making them more cardboard-thin than paper-thin.
I thought about using a Pixmap to detect and extend the edge pixels and give the image some Three-Dimensionality. I also considered duplicating the image along the x-axis to give the same effect. Of the two ideas, the Pixmap holds out the most promise in my mind. However, I'm wondering if there's a better solution.
I'm using a GLSL shader to give the entities highlights and shadows while turning, as you saw in the gif. I think that with the right knowledge, I could achieve what I'm going for using the same shader program.
My shader looks like this:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

uniform vec3 color;

void main()
{
    vec4 col = vec4(color, 0.0);
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords) * v_color + col;
}
```

I think that one might be able to make calculations based on the `uniform vec3 color` that I pass it (with its values ranging from `0, 0, 0` to `1, 1, 1`. 1's being highlight and 0's being shadow). Unfortunately, I don't have the understanding of shaders to do so.
If any of you have the know-how, could you steer me in the right direction? Or let me know if I should just stick to the Pixmap idea.
**Edit:** I'm trying to stay away from using a 3D model because I'm 6.4k lines of code deep using a 2d Orthographic Camera.
**Edit 2:** I figured that the reflection shader wouldn't look good if I tried making the sprite look 3D. I scrapped the shader, went with the Pixmap idea, and plan on implementing shadows and reflections to the pixmap without any shader. Though it looks good so far without reflections.

Comment: I think you'll need to create a 3d mesh of a rectangular block, the uv texture coordinates for your sprite would be the same for the front face and back face of your block. Then when you spin the block around you should see the width of your block. I think the blending should work, but it's not something I've tried before. Not sure how well it will work with a 2D camera.

Comment: Yeah, I think you need extra rectangles on your mesh for the two edges that might show. Extending the Pixmap or doing something in the shader won't create the extra geometry you need to give it any thickness at the moment when it is perpendicular to the camera view. You could theoretically do a calculation using the Pixmap to calculate the appropriate image for the edge, but to have it as part of your atlas I would just draw it manually.

Comment: Have you considered simply drawing it in 3D while it's turning?

Comment: @user253751 I considered it but I've never worked in 3D before besides modeling. I'm hesitant to learn it

Comment: If you don't have too many characters in your game you could simply pre-render that turning animation and use it like that, as anim frames. Or, use some pre-rendered frames just for couple of frames, the most critical ones. Since image is squashed then you could even use the same animation for all characters - difference won't be visible.

Comment: So are you currently "flipping" the sprite using scaling, not 3D?

Comment: @MilanG I'll end up having many, many characters of different shapes and sizes.

Comment: @Tenfour04 exactly.

Comment: I can kind of envision a shader that does what you're describing if you don't flip the region in 3D. It would involve sampling the texture a bunch of times horizontally at increasing spacing as the sprite is scaled down horizontally. Of the sample points, take the max opacity and closest RGB of a non-zero opacity point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with my pixmap idea. I want to share my code so that others can know how I got 2D thickness to work.

#### Please note that in the following code:

> `dir` is a floating point value in the range **-1.0 to 1.0**. It tells the program where the sprite is in its turn. `-1` means facing fully left. `1` meaning right. `0` means that it's 'facing' the camera.

> `right` is a boolean that tells the program which direction the entity is turning. `true` means that the entity is turning from left to right. `false` means from right to left.

#### The Code:

```
private Texture getTurningImage(TextureRegion input, int thickness)
{
    if(Math.abs(dir) < 0.1)
        dir = (right ? 1 : -1) * 0.1f;
    Texture texture = input.getTexture();
    if (!texture.getTextureData().isPrepared()) 
    {
        texture.getTextureData().prepare();
    }
        
    Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
        
    Pixmap p = new Pixmap(64, 64, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    p.setFilter(Pixmap.Filter.NearestNeighbour);
        
    Pixmap texCopy = new Pixmap(input.getRegionWidth(), input.getRegionHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

    // getting a texture out of the input region. I can't use input.getTexture()
    // because it's an animated sprite sheet
    for (int x = 0; x < input.getRegionWidth(); x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < input.getRegionHeight(); y++) 
        {
            int colorInt = pixmap.getPixel(input.getRegionX() + x, input.getRegionY() + y);
            Color c = new Color(colorInt);
            colorInt = Color.rgba8888(c);
            texCopy.drawPixel(x, y, colorInt);
        }
    }
    pixmap.dispose();

    float offsetVal = Math.round(thickness/2.0) * (float) -Math.cos((dir * Math.PI)/2);
    if(offsetVal > -1.23/Math.pow(10, 16))
    {
        offsetVal = 0;
    }

    // generate the pixel colors we'll use for the side view
    Pixmap sideProfile = new Pixmap(1, 64, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

    for (int y = 0; y < texCopy.getHeight(); y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < texCopy.getWidth(); x++) 
        {
            int colorInt = texCopy.getPixel(x, y);
            if(new Color(colorInt).a != 0 && new Color(texCopy.getPixel(x + 1, y)).a == 0)
            {
                Color c = new Color(colorInt);
                c.mul(.8f); // darken the color
                c.a = 1;
                colorInt = Color.rgba8888(c);
                sideProfile.drawPixel(0, y, colorInt);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    // drawing the bottom layer
    p.drawPixmap(texCopy, 0, 0, 64, 64, (int) (Math.round(-offsetVal) + (64 - texCopy.getWidth()*Math.abs(dir))/2), 0, (int)(64*Math.abs(dir)), 64);

    // drawing the middle (connecting) layer
    // based on the edge pixels of the bottom layer, then translated to be in the middle
    for (int y = 0; y < p.getHeight(); y++) 
    {
        int colorInt = sideProfile.getPixel(0, y);
        for (int x = 0; x < p.getWidth(); x++) 
        {
            if(new Color(p.getPixel(x, y)).a != 0 && new Color(p.getPixel(x + 1, y)).a == 0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i <= 2 * Math.round(Math.abs(offsetVal)); i++) // the for the length between the top and bottom
                {
                    p.drawPixel(x + i - 2 * (int)Math.round(Math.abs(offsetVal)), y, colorInt);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // drawing the top layer
    p.drawPixmap(texCopy, 0, 0, 64, 64, (int) (Math.round(offsetVal) + (64 - texCopy.getWidth()*Math.abs(dir))/2), 0, (int)(64*Math.abs(dir)), 64);

    // flip if facing left
    if(dir < 0)
    {
        p = flipPixmap(p);
    }

    return new Texture(p);
}
```

**My `flipPixmap` method looks like this (stolen from stack overflow):**

```
private Pixmap flipPixmap(Pixmap src) 
{
    final int width = src.getWidth();
    final int height = src.getHeight();
    Pixmap flipped = new Pixmap(width, height, src.getFormat());

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
        {
            flipped.drawPixel(x, y, src.getPixel(width - x - 1, y));
        }
    }
    return flipped;
}
```

Here's the result :D https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejhKg.jpg